# Convert Large Scale Kivy Applications to APK With Buildozer Using Google Colab

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

Yesterday I Build A Compleate Game With Kivy and KivyMD Then I Convert It To APK But When I Open And Install That APK Then While Opening It Start With The Kivy Loding Screen And Then It Crashes .

[Watch That Video Of The Projects and Kivy Lerning Video That I Have Made](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8Imtec4ReQ&t=4229s)

Comment: use lower case text.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I Did not get error and apk is built but when i install it and open it . Then it Closes Suddenly .

Comment: can you run it in some console/terminal? Maybe it would show error message and it would explain what is the problem.